# Location of Quick View template

Tags: product, template, quickview

I am using Athlete Package in Magento 1.8.1.0. I would like to know the location of template of **Quick View** button which I get when I hover mouse on any Product.

[image]

Comment: you are using athlete theme. you can use Template Path hints.    this extension is useful - https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html

Comment: @Same Magento comes with built-in template path hints. The most compelling reason to use an extension would be for template path hints in the admin panel.

Comment: @ryanF right it also helps in frontend also

Comment: @Same I just don't personally see the need to install an additional extension for this behavior. I also haven't used the extension you've suggested, so maybe the formatting is nicer than that built-in functionality, I'm not sure. I do know that a solution to the OP's question is available without any additional extensions. Personal preference I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Admin Panel: `System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer`

[image]

You need to modify the scope of the configuration to either a store group or store view. Then enable `Template Path Hints`.

Once this has been set, clear your cache (if enabled) and then go to the frontend. You'll now see information on templates. You'll also see the names of blocks if you enabled block hints as well.

Comment: Thanks @ryanF for your reply. I know the way you showed. But I can see **Quick View** button when I hover the mouse on any product. That's why I could not find out the template location of **Quick View** button. Thanks.